# How to serialize only property names when object is empty?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have working code for serialization into json:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

 public async Task<string> Handle(ConvertToJsonQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
       return Serialize(PrepareObjectForSerialization(request), LanguageEnum.HR);
    }


 private object PrepareObjectForSerialization(ConvertToJsonQuery request)
    {
        Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(Type.GetType(request.TypeOfList));
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(request.Data, listType);
    }


private string Serialize(object obj, LanguageEnum lang)
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new MultiLangResolver(lang),
                Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
                
            };
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);  
        }
```

And this code works if `request.Data` is not empty. Example:

```
  [
        {
            "Institution": "19.10.",
            "FemaleTotal": 1,
          
        },
        {
            "Institution": "my institution",
            "FemaleTotal": 2,
        }
]
```

But, if it is empty I get `[]` as a response.
How to change this, so when `request.Data` is empty I get only property names.
For example above, if `request.Data` is empty I should get

```
  [
        {
            "Institution": null,
            "FemaleTotal": null             
        }
]
```

Comment: Json string you want is not valid

Comment: I edited it so it is valid

Comment: And you have to show your class you are trying to serialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serialize an instance you will need the class like this

```
public class Data
{
    public string Institution { get; set; }
    public int? FemaleTotal { get; set; }
}
```

string is nullable by default,if you make FemaleTotal nullable too, you will get this json by default, you don't need any serializer options

```
[
  {
    "Institution": null,
    "FemaleTotal": null
  }
]
```